# GeoServer does not show some shapefiles using Add Store

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I am working the GeoServer tutorials from Intro to GeoServer via Packt Publishing.

I'm trying to add a shapefile via AddStore using the GeoServer GUI. I can browse to, "see" and publish shapefiles that come with the GeoServer install and are located in the GeoServer data did, but I can't "see" shapefiles I've downloaded myself, even though I can browse to the directory where they live.

I downloaded a county shapefile from the census site given in the GeoServer beginners guide, the files are consistent with the tutorial, but the directory appears empty when I try to add it via Add Stores.

Do I need to restart GeoServer? Is there a file I'm missing?

Comment: The shapefiles you downloaded - are these unzipped from their compressed folders?

Comment: Yes, they are unzipped from their compressed folders.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I downloaded to my Mac, then used Cyberduck to upload to linux system where the files appeared to be unzipped, but invisible to Geoserver.

Comment: I tried doing a wget directly from my linux system and manually unzipped them there...now Geoserver can "see" them. Thanks!